# Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I know there have already been similar questions asked, however, none of the information I have found has helped me.

Aim:

I am trying to set up data stream processing using AWS EMR that is running Flink and Hadoop and saves the output to the S3 bucket.

Flink job, when started is working perfectly fine, it is able to process data and send output back to the required server when the job does not have a line that is supposed to save the output to the S3.

According to the official flink documentation: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/ I have to configure Hadoop S3 filesystem implementation, however they also say:

> You don’t have to configure this manually if you are running Flink on EMR.

The problem:
When I am running the Flink job that contains a code where the output should be saved to the S3, I am getting error:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'Flat Map -> (Map -> Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Unnamed)': Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugins: flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/plugins.html for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.
```

The error itself sort of says what is the problem and it tells me to put the flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin in the plugins directory, which I do, but it does not change the outcome.

Additional information:

Flink version: 1.14.2

Hadoop version: 3.2.1

plugins path: /usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/ (edited typo)

pom.xml:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>ai-preprocessed-data/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>SocketWindowWordCount</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>allinone</shadedClassifierName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.commons</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.apache.commonsv3_6_1</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>regions</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.130</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20220320</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Please let me know if there is something that I may be missing. Thank you!

Comment: Is `haoop` a typo? Anyway, I suspect the _jar_ should be in `plugins/`, not a directory containing the jar.

Comment: @erip yes its just a typo I did here. According to documentation it should be in specific subfolder. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/filesystems/overview/

Comment: Have you tried switching from s3 to s3a ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes I have, the outcome is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you share pom.xml? How do you start the Flink job?

Comment: @bzu added pom.xml above. I run flink job from emr interface. (add step)

Comment: I have org.apache.flink:flink-connector-files dependency added, other than that I don't see why it wouldn't work. I used add step also to copy hadoop plugin to correct folder.

Comment: @bzu I have tried adding your mentioned dependency before, that also did not help.

Comment: I have no experience with Flink on EMR but did you make sure that the S3 hadoop plugin is moved into the plugins folder on each of Flink's JM/TM nodes?

Comment: Did you try adding [hadoop-aws](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws), which is what the error refers to as missing?